# How to enable "resizeableActivity" for only a singe Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, foldable-devices

I am using samsung's foldable device - Galaxy Z Fold3 5G

I need to set `resizeableActivity = true` of only a single activity.

I cannot set it in main `<application`> tag as it will be applied to the whole app.

```
<application
     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_configuration"
     android:resizeableActivity="false"
     tools:targetApi="n">
.....
.....

</application>
```

I've also tried writing it in the `<activity>`, but it is not working there.

```
<activity
      android:name=".PlayVideo_Act"
      android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
      android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:resizeableActivity="true"
      android:screenOrientation="locked"/>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`android:resizeableActivity="false"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#resizeableActivity)` to individual activities that are not large screen optimized. Note the caveats for different API levels that are called out in the linked documentation, and further the guidance provided in the [guide on multi-window support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support).